# Ajax call fails when passing Json over certain size

Tags: json, ajax, model-view-controller

I have the following code that passes a JSON object to an AJAX call...

```
  var jsonResultStr = $j("#HiddenLiveJson").val();
  var jsonResult = JSON.parse(jsonResultStr);

  var serviceURL = appRoot + 'Register/ImportTasks'

  $j.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url: serviceURL,
   data: { 'jsonResultsStr': jsonResultStr },
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: successFunc,
   error: errorFunc
  });
```

The Json is sourced from an XLSX file so could potentially be any size.

If a relatively small JSON set is passed, say 7 items in the JSON, then the AJAX call passes successfully, the controller action is hit and my data is imported. However, if a larger JSON dataset is passed then it consistently fails (HTTP Status 400) without even going anywhere near the controller action. I don't seem to be able to find any suggestion anywhere what is causing this. My first guess, obviously, is the size of the XLSX file.

btw... The JSON used in my testing should be sound as the data that is failing is just the same data that succeeds but duplicated to double its size.

**So far, I have tried**
Adding this to my web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000000">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

And also this to the appSettings in web.config:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1500000000" />
```

And also setting the following:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1000000000" .../>
```

None of which have made any difference.
Any more suggestions are greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a **POST** request for large JSON object and also stringify the JSON data with  contentType as "application/json" and dataType as "json". 
Replace the 'data' parameter in the ajax call as : 
   data: JSON.stringify(jsonResult)

also in the server size script catch the client side data with a get POST method.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks... Not sure why it was a GET to begin with but this set me on the right track!